# How can I send a DELETE request with parameters using Volley?

Tags: java, android, httprequest, android-volley

I want to send a DELETE request to an API to delete a city with the given id. In the API request documentation it says that the DELETE request requires as parameters the authentication token and the city id. When I run the code below I always get a `com.android.volley.AuthFailureError`.

Here's my code:

```java
void deleteCity(String cityId, final VolleyResponseListener volleyResponseListener){
    String url = baseUrl + "city";

    try {
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("token", token);
        params.put("city_id", cityId);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.DELETE, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try{
                            String success = response.get("success").toString();
                            if(success.equals("true")){
                                volleyResponseListener.onResponse();
                            }else{
                                String errorMessage = response.get("errorMessage").toString();
                                throw new Exception(errorMessage);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            volleyResponseListener.onError(e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println(error);
                        volleyResponseListener.onError("Volley Error");
                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        volleyResponseListener.onError("Param error");
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I solved the problem by adding the city id as a query in the HTTP request and sent the authentication token in the header. Here is the final code:

```java
void deleteCity(String cityId, final VolleyResponseListener volleyResponseListener){
    String url = baseUrl + "city?city_id="+cityId;

   
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.DELETE, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try{
                            String success = response.get("success").toString();
                            if(success.equals("true")){
                                volleyResponseListener.onResponse();
                            }else{
                                String errorMessage = response.get("errorMessage").toString();
                                throw new Exception(errorMessage);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            volleyResponseListener.onError(e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println(error);
                        volleyResponseListener.onError("Volley Error");
                    }
                }){

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

                    if (headers == null || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
                        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    }

                    headers.put("token", token);

                    return headers;
                }


            };
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation say exactly about the authentication token? Do you need to send it as a parameter, or maybe as a header? (If it's the latter, [this article about Volley headers](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/) might help you